# SQL syntax for ORDER BY random sublevel?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I need help with the dumbest of questions. I want to make a query ordered by one field, named 'client_level'. The table has something like 400 rows, and client_level possible values are NULL, 1,2,3,4 and 5.

Those are client levels. I want to order all clients by their client_level. Clients leveled 5 should go before clients level 4 and so on.. that is easy.

```
SELECT * FROM client ORDER BY client_level DESC;
```

The problem is.... I want to randomize each sub-group of clients to make the order inside a client level different each time, and therefore, equilibrated over time and this query does not work as I think it should.

```
SELECT * FROM client ORDER BY client_level, RAND() DESC;
```

I am sure there must be a way, thank you for your answers.
kind regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just misplaced the DESC. try:

```
SELECT * FROM client ORDER BY client_level DESC, RAND();
```

Comment: Thank you mate, appreciate your kindness.:)

Comment: You appreciate Galz's kindness, but not enough to accept the answer?